# How can I save and load art made without a canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm making a pixel art maker, and I have most of the functionality down; however, I want users to be able to save and load their designs made on the page. I've used a grid of divs for the template, but all the examples I've seen of saving and loading used a canvas element. Is there any way to do it with my design, or do I need to redesign it with a canvas?

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
let button = document.querySelector('button');
let high;
let wide;
let color = document.querySelector('.colorChoice').value;

//create cell listeners
function listenCells() {
    let cell = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-square');
    cell.forEach((cell) => {
        cell.addEventListener('click', function() {
            cell.style.backgroundColor = color;
        });
    });
}

//Check for updated color picker
function onChangeColor() {
    color = this.value;
}

document.querySelector('.colorChoice').addEventListener("change", onChangeColor);

//function to build the grid based on user input
function createGrid(height = 25, width = 25) {
    canvas.innerHTML = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        let row = document.createElement('div');
        row.classList.add('row');
        canvas.appendChild(row);
        for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            let cell = document.createElement('div');
            cell.classList.add('grid-square');
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }
    listenCells();
}

//listens for input of rows and columns
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    high = parseInt(document.querySelector('.column-input').value);
    wide = parseInt(document.querySelector('.row-input').value);
    if (Number.isNaN(high) || Number.isNaN(wide)) {
        createGrid();
    } else {
        createGrid(wide, high);
    }
});

//Default grid built on load
window.onload = createGrid(25, 25);
```

```css
/* import pixel font for navbar */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap');

.grid-square {
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    border: 1px black solid;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.canvas {
    max-height: inherit;
    max-width: 75%;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">

    <title>Pixel Art Maker</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1 mx-auto">Pixel Art Maker</span>
    </nav>

    <!-- Container to put grid in -->
    <div class="container shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded mt-5 main">
      
      <div class="container canvas d-flex-inline">
        
      </div>

      <form class="d-flex-inline w-50 mx-auto mt-4">
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div class="form-group w-25 ml-auto mr-2">
            <label class="d-block text-center" for="gridRows">Rows</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control row-input" id="gridRows">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group w-25 mr-auto ml-2">
            <label class="d-block text-center" for="gridColumns">Columns</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control column-input" id="gridColumns">
          </div>
        </div>  
        </form>
        <div class="form-group w-25 mx-auto">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Submit</button>
        </div>
      <form class="d-flex-inline w-50 mx-auto">
        <div class="form-group w-25 mx-auto">
          <label for="color">Color</label>
          <input type="color" class="form-control colorChoice" id="color">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS, then local JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

P.S. I'm using plain JavaScript, no jQuery

Comment: You can call [`canvas.toDataURL();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) to get a URL the has a representation of the image. That URL can be saved to `localStorage`.

Comment: You should definitely move to a canvas design. You should create your drawing functions to take arguments that can recreate the same drawings your Client creates on the GUI. There are a couple of ways to save things; `localStorage` on your Browser like `localStorage.data = JSON.stringify(jsonObjectHere);` and on the Server itself, which I would recommend as long as your Client has an account on your system *(loads of work to do correctly)*.

Comment: Understanding you are using a grid of `<div>`, those  can be serialized down to array of javascript objects with dimension and position properties, content, basic styles etc if that's what you need. That array can then be sent to server, or stored locally . Given enough properties in each object when you need to load it again you create elements for each object and insert in dom. Not sure why you wouldn't use canvas though for the whole thing

Comment: Just store the coords in a map of colors and save the whole as JSON. And contrarily to all other previous comments, I see very good reasons not to use a canvas here: drawing the grid on the canvas means you actually have to have a 12 times bigger canvas than the pixel art, if you wish to remove that grid at export that means you have to redraw everything etc. Pointer events logic would much more complicated etc. Keeping the divs as controls seems reasonable to me, if you need a png output, you can always draw only that on a canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not offering details on the `able to save and load` so I would go with SVG...
If you never heard about SVG you should do some reading:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics

Here is a sample of how the saved document would look like:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     version="1.1" baseProfile="full" 
     height="80px" width="440px">
  <defs/>
  
  <rect fill="rgb(105,10,255)" height="40px" width="40px" x="40px"  y="0px"/>
  <rect fill="rgb(135,20,245)" height="40px" width="40px" x="80px"  y="0px"/>
  <rect fill="rgb(165,30,235)" height="40px" width="40px" x="120px" y="0px"/>
  <rect fill="rgb(195,40,225)" height="40px" width="40px" x="160px" y="0px"/>
  <rect fill="rgb(205,50,215)" height="40px" width="40px" x="200px" y="0px"/>
  <rect fill="rgb(215,60,205)" height="40px" width="40px" x="240px" y="0px"/>
  <rect fill="rgb(225,70,195)" height="40px" width="40px" x="280px" y="0px"/>
  <rect fill="rgb(235,80,165)" height="40px" width="40px" x="320px" y="0px"/>
  <rect fill="rgb(245,90,135)" height="40px" width="40px" x="360px" y="0px"/>
  <rect fill="rgb(255,10,105)" height="40px" width="40px" x="400px" y="0px"/>
 
  <rect fill="rgb(105,255,10)" height="40px" width="40px" x="40px"  y="40px"/>
  <rect fill="rgb(135,245,20)" height="40px" width="40px" x="80px"  y="40px"/>
  <rect fill="rgb(165,235,30)" height="40px" width="40px" x="120px" y="40px"/>
  <rect fill="rgb(195,225,40)" height="40px" width="40px" x="160px" y="40px"/>
  <rect fill="rgb(205,215,50)" height="40px" width="40px" x="200px" y="40px"/>
  <rect fill="rgb(215,205,60)" height="40px" width="40px" x="240px" y="40px"/>
  <rect fill="rgb(225,195,70)" height="40px" width="40px" x="280px" y="40px"/>
  <rect fill="rgb(235,165,80)" height="40px" width="40px" x="320px" y="40px"/>
  <rect fill="rgb(245,135,90)" height="40px" width="40px" x="360px" y="40px"/>
  <rect fill="rgb(255,105,10)" height="40px" width="40px" x="400px" y="40px"/>
</svg>
```

Of course, this is just a small sample with just two rows.
Yours would have one `rect` per your defined pixel.